# Quisiera poder transformar data en zoo

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

Lo que tengo es un libro de excel que tiene de nombre Libro1 y quiero usar la hoja de nombre Soberanos, cuando importo la data a R la data el segundo código transforma esa data en zoo, pero cuando lo guardo como objeto para poder usarlo después no me aparece en la barra "data", sino de "value".

[image: El codigo no arroja data, arroja valor]

```
library("openxlsx")

Sob <- read.xlsx("Libro1.xlsx","Soberanos")

Sob.zoo <- as.zoo(Sob[,-1], order.by = as.Date(Sob[,1],origin="1899-12-30"))
```

Answer (score 0):

La distinción entre **Data** y **Values** en el panel de "Environment", vista tipo lista, es una decisión técnica y de usabilidad de **Rstudio**, nada tiene que ver con **R**. Desconozco si esta documentado oficialmente, pero en lineas generales en el grupo "Data" van objetos `S4`, objetos tipo `data.frame`, listas, matrices, arrays y en general objetos que puedan tener más de una dimensión, mientras que en "Values" tenemos objetos más atómicos con no más de una dimensión.

En tu caso, el `as.zoo` termina convirtiendo una estructura tipo `data.frame` en una serie de tiempo, un tipo de objeto con una única dimensión, de ahí que lo veas debajo de "Values".

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda Patricio, una pregunta adicional. Yo he podido dividir objetos de series de tiempo por rangos de fecha cuando la descargo de internet. ¿Es posible hacer lo mismo para zoo?

Comment: No conozco mucho de `zoo` pero entiendo que debieras poder hacer lo mismo que cualquier serie de tiempo común,